# Filter before copy in shell

Tags: bash, shell, filter, copy, cp

I have a directory with files from Jan 2014 to Nov 2014. Sadly the files have no dates in their name, so the only way I can know which month the file belongs to is by using `ls -lrt` and checking the month there.

So I have to copy these files to another location based on the month the file was created.

```
ls -lrt | grep Oct
```

will give me all the Oct files.

Now, I tried

```
ls -lrt | grep Oct | cp * /../../oct2014
```

This obviously didn't work. Is there anyway I can perform such a task?

Edit: Thank you so much everyone for replying with such great answers complete with an explanation. I am truly humbled. I will try these tomorrow morning.

Further, all files I am dealing with do not have any special characters in their names. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is one way

```
ls -ltr | awk '/Oct/{print $NF}' | xargs -i{} cp {} Newdir
```

Or you could use find

```
find . -type f -newermt "Oct 01" ! -newermt "Oct 31" | xargs -i{} cp {} Newdir
```

More robust find (credit to BroSlow)

```
find .  -type f -newermt "Oct 01" ! -newermt "Oct 31 23:59:59" -print0  | xargs -0 -i{} cp {} Newdir
```

If you need it to be the most accurate thing in the world ever

```
find .  -type f -newermt "Oct 01" ! -newermt "Oct 31 23:59:59.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} cp {} Newdir
```

#### Note

Just thought i would add that whilst parsing ls in some situations is unsafe (due to it not being great at showing special characters, and that most programs terminate arguments by spaces and newlines), if you are aware that all the filenames in the target folder are regular names with no special characters or spaces then it parsing `ls` will work perfectly fine.
.
Obviously the names of the files are at the discretion of the user though, so in most cases where the names can change it would be better to use the `find` solution.

Comment: +1 for the `find` solution, +2 if you protect against some edge cases with `-print0` and `xargs -0`, or `-exec`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Instead of telling people not to parse `ls`, why not tell them to just not put special character and spaces in filenames, as this will cause far more complications than just `ls`. Using regular filenames, there is no problem with parsing ls, and I do so all the time.

Comment: @Jidder I think the `-print0` has to come at the end (before the pipe), otherwise I think the other options will be ignored (do the the implied short circuit `-a` between the options)

Comment: @BroSlow oh yeah, my bad, didn't test. Thanks !

Comment: @Jidder if you're a system administrator, you can't control what (evil) users might do. It's not more difficult to avoid parsing `ls` than to use proper ways—it's even, most of the times, simpler and easier.

Comment: By the way, your `find` commands fail if a file was created on October 31. Try `touch -d '2014/10/31 0:01' missed_file`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf you actually can control what the users do quite easily, also ive updated the answer for your problem :)

Comment: But now your find command fails if a file was created on November 1 at 0:00. Try `touch -d '2014/11/1' wrongly_selected_file`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf there you go.

Comment: You don't need that many `9`'s. Usually the quantum unit of time is nanoseconds (but this might vary with systems and file systems—I'm not expert to tell), so nine `9`'s should be good.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf best to be safe, we don't want a file being incorrectly selected.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid parsing `ls` output otherwise later or sooner you run into problems.

Consider this `find` + `stat` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; ts=$(stat -c '%Y' "$f"); \
      m=$(date -d "@$ts" "+%b"); mkdir -p "$m" && echo mv "$f" "$m"' - {} \;
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, **remove `echo` from above command** as I have purposefully used it for safety reasons.

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` - Will find all files in current directory
- `-exec bash -c` - Will execute bash command line for each file
- `stat -c '%Y' "$f"` - will find last modification time in EPOCH value for each file
- `date -d "@$ts" "+%b"` - Will convert EPOCH value to month name
- `mkdir -p "$m"` - Will create a sub directory with month name
- `mv` command will move all files to respective month directories

Comment: I always use `ls`(not literally) and have never run into problems, you only run into problems if you have awful filenames, which in itself will most likely cause problems elsewhere

Comment: It is not uncommon in Unix systems to have file names with spaces and `ls` output will become unreliable to parse for those filenames.

Comment: This is a good answer. If your `date` supports the `-r` option, you could use it: `f=$1; m=$(date -r "$f" '+%b'); mkdir -p "$m" && echo mv "$f" "$m"`.

Comment: Yes I mentioned *Once you are satisfied with the output remove echo from above command* but let me clarify it further.

Comment: This is an amazing solution, thanks.
But I couldn't use it since I have already manually copied files for some of the months.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cp $(ls -l --full-time | grep '2014-10' | awk '{print $NF}') myfolder --you could do it with find command as well
```

cp - does copy
ls -l --full-time - long listing with year as well
grep search for year and month
awk - just print last column value which is a file name
myfolder is destination folder where you want to copy the files to

Comment: @AvinashRaj I understand the consequences of ls but did OP said anywhere he has irregular named files etc?

Comment: it's just a note for op also.

Comment: @almasshaikh There is nothing irregular about filenames with whitespace or special characters. The fact that a lot of people subscribe to a certain loosely defined 'safe' convention for filenames, doesn't negate the fact that there will always be people who won't follow the same convention or will look to create malicious filenames. And `writing code which will work most of the time, for most people` is synonymous with `writing buggy code`.